# PDO - Get row count before limit applied

Tags: pdo

I have a pagination script which requires the row count(obviously) and the row count returned from my select statement which is limited gives only 20 (because the amount of rows returned is 20) but I actually need the row count BEFORE the limit is applied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to solve this, is by issuing 2 queries:

```
$dbh = new PDO (mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password);

$query = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) FROM mytable");
$query->execute();
$count = $query->fetchColumn();

$query = $pdo->prepare("select * FROM mytable LIMIT 20");
$query->execute();
```

If you are using a where on on the limit query, you must use the same where on the count query.